# The requested OLE DB provider Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0 is not registered. If the 32-bit driver is not installed, run the package in 64-bit mode

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, oledb, export-to-excel

I am creating an SSIS package using Visual Studio 2017.
I have a Win 10 64 bit machine, and MS Office 2016 64 bit.

Source: SQL Server database

Destination: Excel

On the Excel Connection Manager, I selected Excel Version "Microsoft Excel 2016"

The Connection String that's created is below:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0;Data Source=\\MyServer\MyFilePath\MyXLSFile20210303.xlsx;Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES";
```

On the Excel Destination, I am getting this error:

```
The requested OLE DB provider Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0 is not registered. If the 32-bit driver is not installed, run the package in 64-bit mode. An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Service Components"  Hresult: 0x80040154  Description: "Class not registered".
```

My package > Properties > Debugging > Run64BitRuntime is already set to True.

I had installed "Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 64 Bit" (I downloaded it from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920).

I couldn't install the 32 Bit version, since I get the error "You cannot install the 32-bit version of Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 because you currently have 64-bit Office products installed".

How can I fix this error ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a little bit more complicated.

Visual Studio 2017 is a 32-bit application. That's why it needs a 32-bit ACE provider installed on the dev. machine.

It is possible to have both editions, i.e.32-bit as well as 64-bit, of the ACE provider installed on the same machine. The **/quiet** flag at the command prompt allows to do that.
Please see a screen shot below.

As end result, you would need the following:

- SSIS dev. machine: 32-bit ACE provider, VS with Run64BitRuntime set to  False.
- SSIS run-time on a server, 64-bit ACE provider.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for that tip! `PS> ./accessdatabaseengine.exe /quiet` really installs x86 version of that driver without having to reinstall 64-bit Office!

Comment: Thanks for your tip to install 32 driver using power shell script  PS> ./accessdatabaseengine.exe /quiet it resolved issue.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the SSIS project and select Properties. In

Configuration Properties, select Debugging and change the `Run64BitRuntime` to True.

This will allow a package running in Debug mode to use the 64 bit architecture instead of 32 bit.

Remember to deploy the ACE drivers on the server once you attempt to move the package from your machine to an actual server.

Comment: Thank you very much all for your quick replies. Yitzhak's suggestion worked ! By"SSIS run-time on a server, 64-bit ACE provider", did you mean I need to install the 64-bit ACE Provider "Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 64 Bit" on the server ? (Even though on my DEV machine, the Package Run64BitRuntime is set to False). BTW, after installing the 32 bit ACE Provider on my DEV machine, even when Package Run64BitRuntime is set to True, I don't get the error anymore. Should I still set Package Run64BitRuntime to False ?

Answer (score 0):

For me installing both versions of the ACE driver solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's relevant but I had the same problem with any applications that are made with "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.xx.0" in Microsoft Visual Studio IDE (in my case it's VS 2022). The next thing helped me. Open the properties of your project and get to "Compile" setting. Uncheck the box "Prefer 32-bit"