# Load XLSX/XLSB format excel in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, etl

Trying to load Xlsx/Xlsb Excel format into SSIS
I followed the below links but I cannot achieve the requirement:

- [Import Excel binary files into SQL Db using SSIS](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/import-excel-binary-files-into-sql-db-using-ssis)
- [The requested OLE DB provider Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0 is not registered. If the 32-bit driver is not installed, run the package in 64-bit mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66462282/the-requested-ole-db-provider-microsoft-ace-oledb-16-0-is-not-registered-if-the)
- [SSIS Excel Connection Manager failed to Connect to the Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23896901/ssis-excel-connection-manager-failed-to-connect-to-the-source)

The Connection String that's created is below:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0;Data Source=\\MyServer\MyFilePath\sample.xlsx;Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES";
```

On the Excel Destination, I am getting this error:

> The requested OLE DB provider Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0 is not registered. If the 32-bit driver is not installed, run the package in 64-bit mode. An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Service Components"  Hresult: 0x80040154  Description: "Class not registered".

Comment: Have you installed the [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920) yet? Download and install `accessdatabaseengine.exe` for 32-bit drivers, or `accessdatabaseengine_X64.exe` for 64-bit drivers. I know it says "Access," but it includes OLEDB drivers for Excel as well.

Comment: I have installed the accessdatabaseengine_X64.exe. Is there anything i should do after the installation?